# CORS Request to Google's Finance Market News

Tags: angularjs, json, get

I would like to get the data from the following endpoint https://www.google.com/finance/market_news?output=json using an http request using AngularJS.

Please find below functional solution which works only on localhost:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.google.com/finance/market_news?output=json',
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    transformResponse: angular.identity
  })
   // Geting the data.
  .then(response => response.data)
  // Normalising JSON.
  .then(data => {
    let myRegexp, match;
    do {
      myRegexp = /({|,)(\w+):/g;
      match = myRegexp.exec(data);
      if (match) {
        data = data.replace(match[0], `${match[1]}"${match[2]}":`);
      }

    } while(match);

    return JSON.parse( data ).clusters;
  })
  .then(news => {
    this.news = news;
  })
```

### Question How Do I make it work on a server?